# How to display multiple variables in drop down list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I create a drop down list which displays the employees name as well as badge number?

At the moment I have:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:employee_id, Employee.all, :id, :name) %>
```

And I want to do something like:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:employee_id, Employee.all, :id, :badge_number + :name) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Employee` model put a method:

```
def badge_name
  "#{badge_number} - #{name}"
end
```

And use it in your view:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:employee_id, Employee.all, :id, :badge_name) %>
```